# What does C# do when typecasting a letter to an int?

Tags: c#, php, casting

We've to implement an encryption for an external interface. The owner of the interface has given documentation of how to preform the same encryption on our side. However, this documentation is in C# and we work in PHP.

Most of the parts we understand except for where they seem to typecast a hash to an int. Their code reads:

```
// hashString exists and is a md5 a like string
int[] keyBuffer = new int[hashString.length];
for (int i=0; i<hashString.length; i++) {
    keyBuffer[i] = (int)hashString[i];
}
```

In PHP, when casting a letter as int, you get 0 (int). As we can't imagine this is what the third party means, we believe C# does something else.

**Does C# also cast to int 0, or possibly to a char?**

Second, the original hashString is 320 long. This means the code will be creating an int which is 320 long?? In PHP you don't have this idea of reserving memory as C# does here. But when we try to typecast a 320 long string to an int we get an int which is 19 'chars' long.

**Does C# also create a shorter int when typecasting a really long 'number' in a string?**

Comment: One question at a time... (usually)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're converting a `char` to `int`. A `char` is a UTF-16 code unit - an unsigned 16-bit integer (the range is `[0, 65535]`). You get that value, basically, widened to a 32-bit signed integer. So `'A'` ends up as 65, for example, and the Euro symbol (U+20AC) ends up as 8364 (0x20ac).

As for your second part - you're creating an `int`, you're creating an `int` *array*. An yes, you'll be creating an array with 320 elements.

Comment: In PHP in "int array" doesn't really exist. Except for a normal array with int values. Is that the same?

Comment: @Lode: I strongly suggest you try to learn about C# *without* using PHP as a reference. You'll end up with a lot more clarity than if you try to map each C# concept onto a PHP concept. In particular, I believe PHP arrays are very different from C# arrays.

Comment: @John, I guess :-) Except that that is not in my interest at all. But now I re-read your answer and I think C# and PHP are quite alike here. An array with 320 integer elements is ok. The only difference being C# can handle the thing as an int and PHP only sees an array.

Comment: @Lode: No, C# can't "handle the thing as an int". An int array is an int array, not a single integer.

Comment: @John, ok thanks for clarification! Then PHP and C# are even more similar.

Comment: @Lode: Not really, based on my reading of [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), which shows that arrays can have string keys etc.

Comment: @John, true, not the same, but similar. For handling this code example it seems to be usable in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

C# strings are UTF16. When you cast a UTF16 character to an int, it merely copies the 16-bit UTF16 character value into the 32-bit int.

Answer (score 1):

C# can cast a character to an int and will give you the character code.The code above is taking a string, `hashString`, and turning it into an array of integers, `keybuffer`. C# is capable of treating a string like an array of chars using the indexer `[]` syntax. The code above will produce an array of ints, one per character in the hash string, and each int will be the character code of the corresponding character.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jon Skeet's post, your "decimal" **integer** values will map to the corresponding **char** values like in the chart below (which I have had on my development PCs for years).

So, casting the `integer` value 0 to a `char` will return a `NULL`.

[image: ASCII Table]

**EDIT:** Looking at your original question, it is possible you would be better served looking at an [MD5 Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-calculate-a-md5-hash-from-a-string_3f00_.aspx) instead of casting the string to an array of integers.

Comment: I can imagine what happens when casting a string "0" or "5" to an int. But what happens when casting "A" or "F" (letters from the md5) to an int?

Comment: Casting `A` maps to 65. `F` maps to 70; however, I'm not sure this is going to relate to your MD5 algorithm.

Comment: "0" becomes 48.  "A" becomes 65.

Answer (score 1):

The code actually cast the `char` (normally ASCII) into an `int`, not '0' to 0. So if the original string is "d131dd02c5e6eec4", the resulting array will be int[]{100, 49, 51, 49, 100, 100, 48, 50, 99, 53, 101, 54, 101, 101, 99, 52}.

So I imagine you need the function `ord` in your PHP script.

**EDIT:**

A bit remarks, casting a `string` to `int` in PHP may actually phrase it into `int`, and the largest `int` PHP handles is either 32-bit or 64-bit depending on the OS, that's why you get a 19-char long int, which is the maximum of 64-bit int.

In C#, there is another variable type called `char`, which represents one unicode character, and can cast directly into integer. You cannot cast a `string` in C# into an `int` directly in C#.

**EDIT2:**
I imagine your PHP script to look like this:

```
<?php
$keyBuffer = new array();
for ($i=0; $i<strlen($hashString); $i++) {
    $keyBuffer[$i] = ord($hashString[i]);
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying. Our PHP now looks exactly like that indeed.